# Remove the automatic two spaces between columns that Pandas DataFrame.to_string inserts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, display

I'm looking for a solution to remove/turn off the 2 spaces between columns that [`df.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) creates automatically.

Example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame()
df = df.append({'a':'12345', 'b': '12345'})
df.to_string(index=False, header=False)
'12345  1235'
```

For clarity, the result is: '12345..12345' where the dots represent actual spaces.

I already tried the [`pandas.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) and [`pandas.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) documentation.

EDIT: The above example is overly simplified. I am working with an existing df that has spaces all over the place and the output text files are consumed by another blackbox program that is based off char-widths for each line. I've already figured out how to reformat the columns with formatters and make sure my columns are not cutoff by pandas default so I am 90% there (minus these auto spaces).
FYI here are some good links on `to_string()` formatting and data-truncation:

- [Convert to date using formatters parameter in pandas to_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347868/convert-to-date-using-formatters-parameter-in-pandas-to-string)
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9784

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Well the stupid but simple solution is to replace all occurrences of two or more spaces with a single space... after a brief look at the code, I'm not seeing an obvious way to do it

Comment: You can't turn them off, and they are not a regular 2 spaces. They are created because of justification (which will be more apparent if you insert more rows with numbers of different lengths).  Why do you need to do that anyway? If you need a concatenation of columns, then you should do that before printing.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Noah and Qusai. The example is overly simplified for clarity. I have a large df that I am working with that is of all different length columns with plenty of random spaces everywhere. A new task that came out of this project was to write out text files that is to be consumed by another program. I cannot touch the other program and it has a specific width of characters that it 'reads' for each column. Since I already have a df and saw there was a to_string option I figured I would give it a shot, but I ran into this issue

Comment: @PydPiper You could try to do the conversion with `re.sub` manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pd.Series.str.cat` method, which accepts a `sep` keyword argument. By default `sep` is set to `''` so there is no separation between values. Here are the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html

You can also use `pd.Series.str.strip` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace from each value. Here are the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html

Here's an example based on what you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['12345'], 'b': ['12345']})
df.iloc[0].fillna('').str.strip().str.cat(sep=' ')
```

Note that `fillna('')` is required if there are any empty values.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this post is old, just in case that someone else comes nowadays like me:

`df.to_string(header=False, index=False).strip().replace(' ', ''))`

Comment: Remember to wrap code snippets with `` so that it looks nicer for readers.

Comment: This will remove spaces that are part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. There is a justify option in to_string() which is supposed to help in this case. But I ended up doing it the old way:

```
[row['a']+ row['b'] for index, row in df.iterrows()]
```