# Python pandas, how to remove extra white space between columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame.to_string() uses one extra white space between columns for sign alignment.
How to remove it?

## **INFORMATION**

- I have a fixed field file: adb.dat , which fixed length for each row is 93.
  adb.dat

```
20230731;                                                                                     
7914785201501236AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201502341AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201503455AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201501232AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201502347AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
00000005;
```

But when I use DataFrame.to_string(), and write this string to a new file,
the length of each row is 94.

## **First try**

According to pandas-dev git, issue#571 said this is a justify problem, so I followed their discussion and tried, but I cannot get my expected result.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/571

Here is my code

```
    df= pd.read_fwf(py_file_fullnm,
    skiprows=1,
    skipfooter=1,
    header=None,
    names=['content1','content2'],
    colspecs=[(0,16),(16,93)],
    delimiter="\0",
    skipinitialspace =True,
    dtype='string')  

    data=df.to_string(index=False,header=None,justify='right')
    print(data)
    with open('testing.dat','w') as editor:
        editor.write("20230731;  ")
        editor.write("\n"+data)
        editor.write("\n00000007;   ")
```

## **Second try**

According to [Remove the automatic two spaces between columns that Pandas DataFrame.to_string inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030631/remove-the-automatic-two-spaces-between-columns-that-pandas-dataframe-to-string)

We can use

```
df.iloc[0].fillna('').str.strip().str.cat(sep=' ')
```

to remove the space between each column, it works, but the length become shorter than first try, field length is 61.

Here is my code

```
    df= pd.read_fwf(py_file_fullnm,
    skiprows=1,
    skipfooter=1,
    header=None,
    names=['content1','content2'],
    colspecs=[(0,16),(16,93)],
    delimiter="\0",
    skipinitialspace =True,
    dtype='string')

    with open('testing.dat','w') as editor:
        editor.write("20230731;  ")
        for i in range (0,5):
            data=df.iloc[i].fillna('').str.strip().str.cat(sep='')
            editor.write("\n"+data)
        editor.write("\n00000005;   ")
```

Any method I can use to remove this extra space between each columns, and keep the same field length? Thank you.

*First try Result*

```
20230731;                                                                                     
7914785201501236 AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201502341 AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201503455 AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201501232 AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201502347 AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
00000005;
```

*Second try Result*

```
20230731;  
7914785201501236AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873
7914785201502341AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873
7914785201503455AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873
6736705201501232AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873
6736705201502347AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873
00000005;
```

*My expected result*

```
20230731;                                                                                     
7914785201501236AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201502341AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
7914785201503455AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201501232AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
6736705201502347AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                
00000005;
```

Comment: Is there a difference between your second attempt and the final result?

Comment: yes, my expexted result the string is like '7914785201501236AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873                                around 30 space here' BUT the second result is '7914785201501236AAA    TEST TEST                     94481873' ,Their field length is different.