# How to format a dataframe column wise in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I used to format the dataframe and output a file by:

```py
tta = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['xx', 'y y', 'z'], 'alter': ['AA', 'BB', 'CCC']})
str1 = tta.to_string(formatters={'name': '{:05s}'.format,
                                 'alter': '{:08s}'.format
                                 }, header=False, index=False, justify='right', col_space=0)
```

However, the `to_string` function adds an extra space to my output string like the `str1` in the script:

```
'xx000 AA000000\ny y00 BB000000\nz0000 CCC00000'
```

It seems it is hard to remove the extra white space.
(See: [Remove the automatic two spaces between columns that Pandas DataFrame.to_string inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030631/remove-the-automatic-two-spaces-between-columns-that-pandas-dataframe-to-string))

Thus is there any elegant way to format the data frame based on the column and let me get results like this:

```
'xx000AA000000\ny y00BB000000\nz0000CCC00000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to achieve this, the space separators seem hardcoded in pandas' source, I didn't find an obvious way to change them. A simple hack however might be to add a custom placeholder (e.g. `-*-`) in your `format` to easily be able to remove it together with the following space afterwards:

```
PLACEHOLDER = '-*-'
str1 = (tta.to_string(formatters={'name': ('{:05s}'+PLACEHOLDER).format,
                                  'alter': '{:08s}'.format
                                  },
                      header=False, index=False, justify='right', col_space=0)
           .replace(f'{PLACEHOLDER} ', '')
       )
```

Output:

```
'xx000AA000000\ny y00BB000000\nz0000CCC00000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

1. **str1.replace(" ","")**
2. from this refrence:[How to Trim a String or Line](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-strip-how-to-trim-a-string-or-line/)  you can use **.strip()** method for trimming the string spaces
   For example:

> ```
> greeting = "     Hello!  "
>
> stripped_greeting = greeting.strip()
>
> print(stripped_greeting,"How are you?")
> ```

**Ensure that the variable's type is str if it is not try to convert it by str(var)**

Comment: Not a common solutions, If a space in the string in the column such as "A AA".

Comment: I used this str1.replace(" ","").replace("\n","") and I got this:
xx000AA000000yyy00BB000000z0000CCC00000

Comment: I update the question now, it seems difficult now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do with the actual [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) but you can try this *workaround* :

```
fmts = {"name": "{:05s}".format, "alter": "{:08s}".format}

str1 = (tta.assign(**{c: tta[c].map(f) for c,f in fmts.items()})
            .astype(str).agg("".join, axis=1).to_string(index=False))

# 'xx000AA000000\ny y00BB000000\nz0000CCC00000'
```