# How To Format Date and Time in Python Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, datetime

I need a way to **reformat** the date and time from **2021-01-27T12:00:17Z** as a separate date and time variable in the format as shown below:

**Date**: 27/01/2021
**Time**: 12:00

```
import pandas as pd

values = {'dates':  ['2021-01-27T12:00:17Z']}

df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


formatted_date = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.date
print('Formatted Date:',formatted_date)
formatted_time = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.time
print('Formatted Time:',formatted_time)

print ('df value:', df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

When I change the syntax from **format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'** to **format='%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%SZ'** it produces an error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Dates in Python are binary values, they have no format. Formats apply *only* when parsing a string into a date or formatting a date into a string.

Comment: Why do you want to "reformat" dates? Do you want to export the data to a CSV or some other text format using a specific date format? That's where you need to specify formatting. Databases and Excel also have binary date types, so they don't need date formats

Comment: The `to_csv` method accepts a `date_format` parameter for formatting dates. For other targets you can pass a date formatter function as [this possibly duplicate question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347868/convert-to-date-using-formatters-parameter-in-pandas-to-string).

Answer (score 0):

I am using these, hope it helps;

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time).astimezone(timezone.utc)
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time).astimezone(local_tz)

date = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).astimezone(local_tz).date
time = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).astimezone(local_tz).time

for datetime calculation, we can use timedelta
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time).astimezone(local_tz) + deltatime(hours=5)
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time).astimezone(local_tz) + deltatime(minutes=60)


<built-in method date of datetime.datetime object at 0x000002BF40795DA0>
<built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x000002BF40795DA0>
```

the date and time are datetime.datetime objects.